# Django modelformset form is not blank when I return

Tags: django-models, django-forms

If the database is empty and I go to my form it looks the way it is supposed to.  There is two spots for parent information and two spots for child information.  If I fill the form out and submit it I get no errors and I get taken to the thank you page.  When I go back to the page with the form there are now four spots for parent information and four spots for child information.  Two of the spots for child and parent information are filled out with the data that is now in the database.  If you fill in the blank fields new data will get added to the database but if you change any information in the already populated fields it will change the information of the data already in the database.  I have even tried manually inputing the data through the admin portal but when I go to the form the information I put in still shows up.  It's like the formset is pulling information out of the database.  How do I get this form so that when I go back to it after submitting data the form is blank again?

[Form after data submission part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmIZC.png)

[Form after data submission part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKnIj.png)

models.py

```
    from django.db import models

class Child(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    birthday = models.DateField()
    allergies = models.CharField(max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

class Parent(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    child = models.ManyToManyField(Child)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name + ' ' + self.last_name

class Household(models.Model):
    household_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    parent = models.ManyToManyField(Parent)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.household_name
```

forms.py

```
    from django import forms
from .models import Child, Household, Parent

class HouseholdForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Household
        fields = ('household_name',)

class ParentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Parent
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name',)

class ChildForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Child
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'birthday', 'allergies',)
```

views.py

```
    from django.forms import modelformset_factory
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render, redirect
from .forms import ChildForm, HouseholdForm, ParentForm 
from .models import Child, Parent, Household


def register(request):
    ParentFormSet = modelformset_factory(Parent, form=ParentForm, extra=2)
    ChildFormSet = modelformset_factory(Child, form=ChildForm, extra=2)
    if request.method == "POST":
        formset1 = ParentFormSet(request.POST, prefix="parent",)
        formset2 = ChildFormSet(request.POST, prefix="child",)
        if formset1.is_valid() and formset2.is_valid():
            formset1.save()
            formset2.save()
        return redirect('thanks',)
    else:
        formset1 = ParentFormSet(prefix="parent",)
        formset2 = ChildFormSet(prefix="child",)
    return render(request, 'register.html', {'formset1': formset1, 'formset2': formset2,})

def thanks(request):
    return render(request, 'thanks.html')
```

Comment: 'Behaving weird' is not clear. "Form is not blank when I return" is better. Be explicit about how it is behaving incorrectly in the subject.

Comment: Are you clicking the back button, or following a link back to the data insertion form? I know nothing about django, but in many toolsets how you get to the page makes a significant difference.

Comment: I am not hitting the back button.